# how to set pin in verilog (atera)

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga

I am beginner in Altera DE2-115. I am asked to make a project using Verilog language. My idea was connect an infrared sensor and if it is cut with something, a buzzer starts.

The  infra has 3 connections: ground , vcc , signal

and the buzzer: vcc and signal

So, for example, if I connect signal1 of infra in to pin 9 and pin 10 for buzzer signal ...
all I know is infra has output 0 or 1, so if it is 0, the buzzer should start; if it is 1, the buzzer should stop.

I can code it in C, but I don't know how to code this in Verilog, so I need a code for this idea in Verilog.

Comment: I think before you do anything, you need to learn Verilog. There are many online tutorials, and examples. Start with compiling and running code in simulation, and only once you understand designing for HDL should you move to hardware. HDL is very different from C, in fact it is very different from any procedural language.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is on the [altera forums](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=39425)

```
module fpga_main {
   out0,
   out1,
   // more i/o pins

};

output out0;
output out1;

assign out0 = 1'b0;  //pin low
assign out1 = 1'b1;  //pin high

// other code

endmodule
```

alternatively for inputs:

```
module fpga_main {
  in0,
  in1,
  // more i/o pins
};

input in0;
input in1;

// other code 

end module
```

to actually connect the code to the pin you want though you need to use Quartus pin assignment feature to route the out0/1 or in0/1 signals to proper fpga pins

Comment: my question is : if i connect the wire of the signal in pin number 9 i want to say in the code set the pin number 9 as input and how to check whether if it 0 or 1

Comment: @Namo see edit please

Comment: thanks for help ,, you mean that in0 means there is a wire connected to pin number 0 if i said in9 this mean there is wire to connect to pin 9 ??

Comment: No, not at all. That is just how you refer to the input signal.  It could be called "bacon" for all it really mattered.  You use the quartus pin assignment tool to connect internal signals to physical FPGA pins

Comment: okay if now i connected wire from the signal pin of the sensor to on of the pins of fpga for example pin number 11 and i need to set this pin as input in c language
i say : int x = 9; // 9 is the number of the pin and then i say pinmode(x,INPUT) ; HOW CAN I SAY THIS IN VERILOG

Comment: Okay, all you do in the code for pin direction assignments is already stated above, `input xx` or `output xx`.  After that all you do is assign it in the Quartus pin assignment tool! Read page 42 of this: https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/tt/tt_my_first_fpga.pdf